# Makefile does not make all targets

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to have the compiled obj files in two different folder

1. `dobjects`: where the objects have the debug symbol (gcc with -g option)
2. `sobjects`: where the objects are compiled without the debug symbols.

Source files are the same,

I have the following makefile.

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall
OBJS = a.o b.o
SRCS = a.c b.c
SOBJS_DIR = sobjects
DOBJS_DIR = dobjects
SOBJS = $(addprefix $(SOBJS_DIR)/, $(OBJS))
DOBJS = $(addprefix $(DOBJS_DIR)/, $(OBJS))

all: release debug

release: $(SOBJS)

debug: $(DOBJS)

$(DOBJS_DIR)/%.o: CFLAGS += -g

$(DOBJS_DIR)/%.o $(SOBJS_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm dobjects/*
    rm sobjects/*
```

---

But every time I try "make" only one target is made.

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -c a.c -o sobjects/a.o
gcc -Wall -c b.c -o sobjects/b.o

$ make
gcc -Wall -g -c a.c -o dobjects/a.o
gcc -Wall -g -c b.c -o dobjects/b.o
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Side note (one day you'll appreciate this): "build your files in the directory that they are supposed to be put in and use `VPATH` to find those source files".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule does not do what you think it does:

```
$(DOBJS_DIR)/%.o $(SOBJS_DIR)/%.o: %.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Pattern rules with multiple targets tell make that one single invocation of the recipe will build BOTH targets.  So when make runs that rule to build `$(DOBJS_DIR)/a.o`, make believes that `$(SOBJS_DIR)/a.o` was also built, so it doesn't try to run the rule to build it.  But your rule doesn't actually build it, so when you run make a second time it sees that object file is missing and runs the above rule again, to build the missing one.

You have to write this as two different rules:

```
$(DOBJS_DIR)/%.o: %.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(SOBJS_DIR)/%.o: %.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thank you. I am new to makefiles and the journey is not really pleasant until now.